# R {hexbin} libraryを使用してplotする時のx-y rangeの設定について

Tags: r

Rを使って、図を作成する時に、
x-y座標のサイズを設定する方法について質問させていただいております。

先に使用するサンプルデータ及び問題があるコードを書かせていただきます。

以下のデータをsample.dataとして使用しています。

```
1247211284201945,A-vector-1,0.028382835,0.327685692,0.288425494
1247211284201945,A-vector-10,-0.012618369,0.158331365,0.18369201
1247211284201945,A-vector-11,0.059614712,0.210239257,0.138845855
1247211284201945,A-vector-13,-0.07040885,-0.00684115,0.071109223
1247211284201945,A-vector-14,-0.043941759,0.166591033,0.223211813
1247211284201945,A-vector-15,0.026459552,-0.001095527,-0.023953769
1247211284201945,A-vector-16,0.054251654,-0.069467257,-0.11831891
1247211284201945,A-vector-17,0.058789968,0.021960568,-0.035599055
1247211284201945,A-vector-18,-0.035810968,0.029101298,0.05980141
1247211284201945,A-vector-19,-0.005040805,-0.020944664,-0.008700876
```

このデータの３列目と４列目を使用する仮定してください。
そのときに使用したコードは、

```
library(hexbin)
read.table("sample.data", sep=',')->DATA
bin<-hexbin(DATA[[3]], DATA[[4]], xbins=10, xbnds=range(-0.8,0.1), ybnds=range(-1,2))
plot(bin, main="Hexagonal Binning")
```

ここでは、x座標を-0.8から0.1まで、y座標を-1から2までを想定しています。
しかし実際にplotしてみますと、
x座標は、-0.1から0.15、
y座標を、-0.4から0.4
になってしまっています。

xbndsやc(), xlimなどいろいろなものを試したのですが、x-yのサイズを自分がほしいレンジに設定することができませした。webでも探してみましたが、設定の方法がわかりませんでした。

もしhexbinを使用して図を作成するときに、x-yサイズを設定する方法をお知りの方は、ご教授をお願いします。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `hexbinplot()` を使うのはどうでしょうか。`hexbinplot(DATA[[4]]~DATA[[3]], xbins=10, xbnds=range(-0.8,0.1), ybnds=range(-1,2), main="Hexagonal Binning", aspect=1, xlim=c(-0.8,0.1), ylim=c(-1,2))` ただ、counts の値が異なってしまっているのですが…

Comment: 返信が大変遅くなり、申し訳ありませんでした。
Argusさんが指摘されたhexbinplot()は不勉強のため認知しておりませんでしたが、hexbinplot()を使うことで、うまくいきました。現在でもcountsの値についてはまだ解決方法がありませんが、少しは前進しました。ありがとうございました。